# A few problems with generating in jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-autocomplete

I'm not very good yet in javascript, so I need some assistance. I started using the jQuery Autosuggest Plugin, which allows me to add tags (somewhat like stackoverflow tagging). What I want to do is, generate a checkbox for every selected tag. For this reason, I've modified the plugin, so that it wraps each tag name in a `<span class="tag tag_name">tag_name</span>`, so It's easier to get the tag, which I do like this: `$(".tag").attr("class").replace("tag ", "");`. Anyhow, I've written up a script, that generates a check-box, but the problem is, that it only generates a checkbox for the first tag, and it keeps generating that every 2 seconds. Also, I'm worried that the script might be a bit too much on preformance? Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var done = {};
    $("input[type=text]").autoSuggest("get.php", {searchObjProps:"name", selectedItemProp:"name", asHtmlID: "1"});
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        if(!done[city]){
            var city = $(".mestoJe").attr("class").replace("mestoJe", "");
            done[city] = true;
        }
        var nr = 0;
        $.each(done, function(i, j){
            if(j != 2){
                var tmp = $('<input type="checkbox" value="'+nr+'" name="city[]">'+i+'<br />');
                $("#checkboxes").append(tmp);
                j = 2;
                nr++;
            }
        });
    },2000);

});
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you adding checkboxes on a 2 second interval timer forever?  Why not just add all the ones you want and be done.  Why not stop the timer when you're done adding all checkboxes?

Comment: How would I do that? I'm really stupid with this :S

Comment: Stopping the timer is done with `clearInterval(timer)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line of your script:

```
var city = $(".mestoJe").attr("class").replace("mestoJe", "");
```

you are calling `.replace()` to remove the class name, but not assigning it back to anything so nothing is actually changing.  `.replace()` returns the replaced string - it does not modify the one passed in.

To actually change the classname and thus advance to the next city the next time the timer fires, you would have to use something like this:

```
var firstCity = $(".mestoJe").get(0);
var city = firstCity.className = firstCity.className.replace("mestoJe", "");
```

If you don't change the class name, then this line of code will generate the exact same result and the exact same city name every time:

```
var city = $(".mestoJe").attr("class").replace("mestoJe", "");
```

In addition, you are starting a 2 second internval timer and never stopping it so it goes on forever.

You are also referencing:

```
if(!done[city]){
```

before you've ever defined `city`.

Comment: Actually, the class is like this: `<span class="mestoJe city">city</span>`, so I get exactly what I want from it. And that wasn't a problem in the first place.

Comment: But, you call this repeatedly on every timer and you get the exact same result every time because you never modify anything: `var city = $(".mestoJe").attr("class").replace("mestoJe", "");`

Comment: Holy moly! I didn't get what you were saying at first, my bad. I thought I could store city name by just replacing it. It actually generates all the checkboxes, but not it only displays the whole array.